# Assigning json to variable

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Ok, some explanation. Even though I don't think it has anything to do with the problem itself. I have a small django project that maps some data using leaflet. On a mouseover some  ajax functionality is added, using the `dajax`(which is a "lightweight library to implement AJAX inside django projects") framework. The call itself looks like this:

```
dajax.add_data(simplejson.dumps(series), 'my_test_flot')
```

My js function receives json data which looks like this (using `alert`)

```
[{"color": "#dddd00", 
"data": [[-0.5, -20.5]], 
"label": "Tweede Zandlaag"}]
```

The object has more data to it but the problem is not with the object. When I copy/paste the data directly into the function `var series = []` the behaviour is as aspected. As aspected means, the graph I'm drawing with `flot` is actually being drawn. Otherwise the graph remains empty.

```
function my_test_flot(dat) {
    function MyFormatter(v, xaxis) {
        return " ";
    }
    $(function () {
        alert(dat)
        var series = dat; // here lies the problem, but why?
        ...
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you are missing a lot of information. For example, how is `my_test_flot` called? I don't think you have to use a `ready` event handler inside the function at all (assuming `$` refers to jQuery).

Comment: The question is quite confusing, please add more code or a better explanation to what you mean.

Comment: You forgot to explain the problem. Also, are you _sure_ it's JSON (a string format), and not a Javascript object?

Comment: Ok, added some explanation. Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. Apparently you have to use  `JSON.parse()`. How it's done is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

This does not copy the data - it just makes `series` a reference to the same object as `dat`. Therefore, if you later modify the object, all users retaining references to it see the changes. This is probably what causes your trouble.